# Inheriting OneToOneField results in TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_name'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I’m using Django 2.2, Python 3.7 and my attempt was to set up some common *kwargs* (say, `on_delete` and `related_name`) to the `OneToOneField`, by a sub class like the following

```
class MyOneToOneField(models.OneToOneField):
    def __init__(self, to):
        super().__init__(to, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='extra_data')
```

And the model class is like

```
class UserExtraData(models.Model):
    entity = MyOneToOneField(USER_MODEL)
```

However, when running *makemigrations*, it results in:

> TypeError: Couldn't reconstruct field entity on UserExtraData: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_name'

(I tried removing all other fields, so I am pretty sure this is the field that caused the issue).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this type of problem, you can change your project settings file. In the settings file, after `INSTALLEDD_APPS`:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL= '<your app name>.<class name>'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you tend to specify the `related_name` in `MyOneToOneField`, do not use an argument passed to it. I prefer

```
class UserExtraData(models.Model):
    entity = models.OneToOneField(USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='extra_data')
```

Or you could try:

```
class MyOneToOneField(models.OneToOneField):
    def __init__(self, to, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(to, *args, **kwargs)
        # Do others

class UserExtraData(models.Model):
    entity = MyOneToOneField(USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='extra_data')
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved the exception but not the problem that I 'd like to decline arguments like `on_delete` to be passed to this field.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it should be like this according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-model-fields/#field-deconstruction):

```
class MyOneToOneField(models.OneToOneField):
    def __init__(self, to, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['related_name'] = 'extra_data'
        kwargs['on_delete'] = models.CASCADE
        super().__init__(to, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thank you. It solved the exception but not the problem that I 'd like to disallow arguments like `on_delete` to be passed to this field. Found a solution by myself. Would be nice if you could give more details or cites about what is suggested by which part of the doc.

Comment: I am glad you found the solution. You made a good suggestion. I updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

I found out it was because Django was going to `clone` the field for some reason. After digging a little, Django's suggested it by the exception traceback:

```
  File ".../django/db/migrations/state.py", line 414, in from_model
    fields.append((name, field.clone()))
  File ".../django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 493, in clone
    return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_name'
```

So take a look at `Field.clone`, whose source is

```
    def clone(self):
        """
        Uses deconstruct() to clone a new copy of this Field.
        Will not preserve any class attachments/attribute names.
        """
        name, path, args, kwargs = self.deconstruct()
        return self.__class__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Apparently the `TypeError` is due to `kwargs` containing `related_name` and `on_delete`, which is returned from `deconstruct`.

Then, the docstring of `deconstruct` says it is to "Return enough information to recreate the field as a 4-tuple:", so I guess I missed that I should have overridden it to provide a `kwargs` that did not contain `on_delete` and `related_name`, but only `to`.

So it finally works like this:

```
class MyOneToOneField(models.OneToOneField):
    def __init__(self, to):
        super().__init__(to, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='extra_data')

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        return name, path, args, {'to': kwargs['to']}
```